# What insane Autolayout logic is this?

Tags: macos, nsviewcontroller, autolayout, nsstackview

I create a new view controller.

I add a vertical stack to it. Spacing = 0, Alignment = Center X, Fill Equally. I constrain it to the 4 edges of its superview with space = 0.\

I add 3 horizontal stacks inside the main stack.

For each of the the horizontal stacks: alignment = Center Y, Fill Equally, spacing 0.

I add two custom views inside each of these 3 stacks.

I constrain the width of one of these stacks to the width of the main stack.

The result is insane.

[image]

Why in the name of heaven isn't the result like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution: you must add a constrain in each of the custom views to Equal height of its stack view.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need **any** constraints except of the top, leading, bottom and trailing constraints for your outer (vertical) stack view. Make sure that you set the `alignment` property to `Fill` and the `distribution` property to `Fill Equally` for **all** (vertical and horizontal) stack views.

**Result:**

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks but this works for iOS but unfortunately not for macOS. There is no alignment FILL there.